# Cloning Ubuntu to a larger partition with Clonezilla

Tags: dual-boot, partitioning, clone, clonezilla

Sometime ago I bought a 480 GB SSD to expand the space in my laptop. On it I have one with 240 GB where is installed a dual boot between Windows 10 and Ubuntu Unity 18.04. The boot type is UEFI.

Okay. What I want to do is install the new SSD in my laptop, where the Windows is going to be totally reinstalled, but the Ubuntu will be cloned, because of my all settings, apps, etc.

So I cloned the Ubuntu using Clonezilla. Just the root and home partitions. The swap one was unaccessible. Later I reinstalled the Windows in a larger partition than before and used GParted to partitionate the unallocated part of the SSD, between swap and two new *ext4* partitions to root and home, where both was also larger than before.

Okay until now. The last thing I did was restore the cloned Ubuntu to the new partitions with Clonezilla and, after restoring the GRUB and doing some others UUID settings, I got logged in. Great!

But the only problem was: as the new partitions are larger than before, I verified their size on *Disks* app and noted that they was a little bigger than they really are. Strangely, when I typed `fdisk -l` on Terminal, I got the correctly sizes.

I guess this is the only problem I had. But what I would to know is if I will have some real problem with it and what can I do to fix it? Did I make some mistake on cloning or restoring the Ubuntu?

If you have any experience about cloning with the Clonezilla, I will appreciate that.

I'm brazilian, so excuse me for my english, if there was any mistakes.

Note: I searched in lots of pages and forums for something like this error, but I didn't succeed. About cloning, I learned in some tutorials over the internet.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

FDISK reports disk size in MiB  (1024KB = 1MB). Does some rounding, too.

Not sure about Clonezilla, but various other utilities report disk size in MB (1000KB = 1MB).

If the difference in partition (disk)) sizes you see are in that neighborhood, you probably don't have a problem.

For example, fdisk reports my / (root) partition is 122.1 GiB.  The disks utility says it's 131 GB.  Both are correct.

To convert use: `1 GiB == 1.07374 GB`.

Comment: I've never seen this particularity. I noticed that the _Disks_ app also shows "wrong" sizes for my old SSD, and the `fdisk -l` shows the "correct" ones. That was totally helpful. Thank you, rbmorse.